# Ubuntu doesn't boot after successful installation on a HP EliteDesk 800 G1

Tags: boot, hp, 19.10

I have been trying to get Ubuntu running on an elderly HP EliteDesk 800 G1.

The installation has been pretty slow already, which has made me suspicious, but nevertheless successful.

However, after the installation has been finished, the system doesn't boot. The screen just turns black. And I don't know how to proceed to find out what the problem could be.

Comment: Shut down laptop and turn it on while pressinng F10 key,system setup will open. Go to advance -->Boot and at the bottom of window you will find boot devices and OSes. [Edit] your answer with that list. This setup can be little bit diferent(like boot options or boot older instead of boot), but  F10 will work on any eldery hp PC

Comment: Hi @V.H., thank you vor your answer. I've already gone into the BIOS/UEFI Setup and selected the SSD directly. Is that what you mean?

Comment: can you find any list with something like this (Ubuntu,usb,cd/dvd, network)?

Comment: Hi V.H., I found out that there was a new BIOS version and it works now. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what exactly the problem was, but I've updated the BIOS and it works now.